# Javascript function if statement not excuted right

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have this little piece of code that is supposed to do something if some `if` conditions are met. It does not work as it should and I could not figure out why. The code is a bit lengthy please bear with me.Any kind of help is really appreciated!

First I have a button in my html, when it is click it will trigger function

```
function coverCard() {
    if (2 > 1) {
    GodAn();
    } else {
      if (bbbbb === 0) {
        do something
       } else {
         do sth
       }
    }
  }
```

This function will lead to `GodAn` function shown as follow

```
function GodAn() {
    var a = 1
    if (a < 2) {
      document.getElementById("coverCard").onclick = Alert.render("do option 1  please")
      bbbbb = 0;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("coverCard").onclick = Alert.render("do option 2  please")
      bbbbb = 2;
    }
  }
```

Finally following is the function defining what is shown in the dialog box and what will happen when its `ok` button is clicked

```
 function CustomAlert() {
     this.render = function (dialog) {
       document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">ok</button>';
     }

     if (bbbbb === 0) {
       this.ok = function () {
         alert("do option1")
         console.log(bbbbb)
       }
     } 
     else this.ok = function () {
       alert("do option 2")
       console.log(bbbbb)
     }
   }

var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

What I expect to happen is when the html button is clicked, the dialog box will show `"do option 1 please"`, (which it always does) and then alert `"do option1"`. However sometimes in the `CustomAlert` function the `"do option 2"` alert will be wrongly triggered, even when the global var `bbbbb` is reset to `0`. (`console.log` also confirms `bbbbb` is `0`).

I have uploaded the original html file and the link is here:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/313ba63c7a101f917cbc9e6f9a4c5ade20170226122032/43cedb

This really drives me crazy so somebody please shed some light here please?

Here is the jsFiddle link to my code

https://jsfiddle.net/5bn0ux5k/

It seems to me that whether alert 1 or alert 2 is triggered is a pure random event while it is expectedly set to just alert 1(option 1)

Comment: you could do yourself a favor and use some indentation for the code.

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle, codepen or snippet illustrating your issue.

Comment: I checked your html, the code is really terribly formatted, this is the first thing you should fix, it will never work for you this way; as for bbbb, you have `var bbbbb =Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` in the beginning of your script, so it gets the random value. Side note - global variables are as bad as the terrible formatting.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my formatting problem I will do my best to fix it. I have not use isFiddle before so not too sure how to get it work there.

Comment: Why do you assume *"if statement not executed right"*, while it seems much more likely it was not coded right....

Comment: would you mind telling me what is not right? It is probably just a minor design issue but I really cannot figure out. I am just starting out coding javascript and I mostly just learn by myself @trincot

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I just did my best re-format my code and put it there  again,the reason I set the global var is because under my current skills, that is my only option to let multiple functions to access its value.I know it is not perfect but I dont understand why the function does not execute right when the global var has been changed. Do you know where goes wrong in my code?@ Boris Serebrov

Comment: I have just included the jsFiddle demo @ jcaron

Comment: Sorry I did not know much about formating but I will improve @T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

You assign a new value to the button `onclick` handler, ... when you click it. This seems wrong, and all the more so because you do not assign it a function:

```
document.getElementById("coverCard").onclick = Alert.render("do option 1 please")
```

What happens here is that the `render` method is executed immediately. This is all very confusing, because it looks like you wanted to do this:

```
document.getElementById("coverCard").onclick = function () {
    Alert.render("do option 1 please");
};
```

... which would make the `render` method execute on the *next* click, but then in your description you say you actually do want the `render` method to execute upon the first click, not on the *next*. So in that latter case, you should just execute the `render` method, and not assign anything to the `onclick` method:

```
Alert.render("do option 1 please");
```

Doing the mix of both is wrong: the `render` method does not return a function, so its result should not be assigned to an `onclick` property. So I'll assume you want just to execute `render`.

The second issue is that you decide the assignment for `this.ok` at the moment the page loads, i.e. when `new CustomAlert()` is executed:

```
if (bbbbb === 0) {
    this.ok = function() {
        alert("do option1")
        console.log(bbbbb)
    }
} else 
    this.ok = function() {
        alert("do option 2")
        console.log(bbbbb)
    }
```

Your decision is based on the value of `b`, which at that moment is random. Later, when you click the button, you change the value of `b` to zero, but that does not influence that earlier decision any more: `this.ok` will not magically change because of setting `b` to zero.

You can correct this, by putting the condition on `b` *inside* the `this.ok` function, like this:

```
this.ok = function() {
    if (bbbbb === 0) {
        alert("do option1")
    } else {
        alert("do option 2")
    }
    console.log(bbbbb)
}
```

Now you will have the correct option mentioned in the `alert`.